# Counting values on click in table

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a table that when you click on it the clicked row turns green and the value that is in the table gets counted, right now it just counts the amount of rows clicked but I want to change this to the amount that is under the value.

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>


  <div class="container">
    Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <table class="table " id="onclick">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>henk</td>
          <td>janssen</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>piet</td>
          <td>Paulisma</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Theo</td>
          <td>van gogh</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Erik</td>
          <td>Doerustig</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jan</td>
          <td>de steen</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>



      </tbody>
    </table>








  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get the row's last TD element by using `.eq( -1 )`
- Get it's `.text()` and use `parseInt` to convert string to integer:

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
  
    var $td = $(this).find("td").eq( -1 );    // Get desired row's cell
    var tdVal = parseInt( $td.text(), 10);    // Convert content string to integer
    
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    
    
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count+= tdVal;
    } else {
      count-= tdVal;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <table class="table " id="onclick">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>henk</td>
        <td>janssen</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>piet</td>
        <td>Paulisma</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Theo</td>
        <td>van gogh</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Erik</td>
        <td>Doerustig</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jan</td>
        <td>de steen</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your trying to do correctly, which is add the value found in the `count` column when you click a row you could do something like this:

```
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count += parseInt($(this).find('td:last-of-type()').text());
    } else {
      count -= parseInt($(this).find('td:last-of-type()').text());
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
 });
```

To this:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
  var value = parseInt($(this).children("td:last").html());
  if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
    count +=value;
  } else {
    count -=value;
  }
  countEl.html(count);
});
```

We grab the last TD, the one with the value, and convert that to INT with parseInt

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to have the sum of all values of column "Count".
By now you're just increasing your local counter. Instead you need to get the value of the column Count and add it to your current value.

So basically you need to change your Javascript like this

```
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    var curCount = parseInt($(this).find('td:last').text());
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {

      count = count + curCount;
    } else {
      count = count - curCount;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My jQuery is pretty rusty, but what you in essence want to do here is find your last table cell in the clicked row and add/subtract that instead of just incrementing/decrementing your counter.

`let amount = Number.parseInt($el.children('td').last().text());`

This line is saying that the amount is equal to an integer found at the last `td` of the clicked row. Then you would add it to your count, the only other complication is the need to subtract if the cell isn't active, it is generally good practice to avoid else conditions (helps remove catch all unexplained effects) so I edited the code to add in all cases and to make the number negative in the case of an inactive cell.

```js
$(function() {
  const $countEl = $('#count');
  let count = 0;
  
  $('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    const $el = $(this);
    let amount = Number.parseInt($el.children('td').last().text());
    $el.toggleClass('green-cell')
    
    if (!$el.hasClass('green-cell')) {
      amount = -amount;
    }
    
    count += amount;
    $countEl.text(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>


  <div class="container">
    Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <table class="table " id="onclick">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>henk</td>
          <td>janssen</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>piet</td>
          <td>Paulisma</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Theo</td>
          <td>van gogh</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Erik</td>
          <td>Doerustig</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jan</td>
          <td>de steen</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>



      </tbody>
    </table>








  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can grab the amount from the last cell from the row by using `cells` property of the `<tr>` element.

```
const amount = +this.cells[this.cells.length - 1].innerText;
if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
  count += amount
} else {
  count -= amount
}
```

Then, instead of incrementing or decrementing, use this value to add/subtract.

---

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    const amount = +this.cells[this.cells.length - 1].innerText;
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count += amount
    } else {
      count -= amount
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>

<table class="table " id="onclick">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>henk</td>
              <td>janssen</td>
              <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>piet</td>
              <td>Paulisma</td>
              <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Theo</td>
              <td>van gogh</td>
              <td>6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Erik</td>
              <td>Doerustig</td>
              <td>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Jan</td>
              <td>de steen</td>
              <td>8</td>
          </tr>  



        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: @downvoter: What's the issue with my solution? I'd like to know so I can improve my code. Thanks!